# Maximum independent sets of $k$-partite graphs

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Consider a $k$-partite graph $G=(V,E)$. This means that its vertices can be partitioned into $k$ different independent sets, say $V_1,\dots, V_k$. 
Assume further that $|V_1|=\dots = |V_k|$.

Under which condition(s) these $k$ independent sets are the only maximum independent sets of the graph $G$?

(This is clearly not always the case, see this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/647602/maximum-independent-sets-of-balanced-bipartite-graph).)

Comment: One such case would be for $G$ to be a $2k$-cycle, which is bipartite with two $k$-subsets of alternating vertices being the only maximum independent sets.

Comment: Sure. Also the $n\times n$ grid graph with periodic boundary conditions and $n$ even is a bipartite graph and the two components are the only maximum independent sets.